# Bound of $\det$ of positive definite matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, matrices, analysis

I need to know that if the following holds for complex vectors $x=[a\cdot A \mid b\cdot B]u$, and $y= [A \mid B]u$
$$\det(I+d \frac{yy^*}{rI})\leq\det(I+\frac{xx^*}{rI})\leq \det(I+c \frac{yy^*}{rI})$$
where $d= \min \{a,b\}$$, c = \max \{a,b\}$ and $r$ are positive real values. $u$ is a complex valued vector and $^*$ means conjugate transform (Hermitian).

By $[A \mid B]$ I mean the composite matrix made from the two matrices $A, B$. Let $A$ and $B$ be complex valued matrices.

It works in simulations. I think it has something to do with eigenvalues of positive definite matrices. I know that $xx^*$ and $yy^*$ are positive definite and so is $I$. Also I think the division by $I$ is not a problem here. But I don't know how to prove it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Presumably both $A$ and $B$ are nonzero matrices and $a\neq b$, i.e. $0<d<c$.*) Contrary to your claim, your inequality **never** holds universally, i.e. we can always find a vector $u$ that violates the inequality.

For any complex scalar $\lambda$ and any complex vector $v$, we have $\det(I+\lambda vv^\ast)=1+\lambda v^\ast v$. Now, suppose $A$ is $n\times p$, $B$ is $n\times q$ and $M=[A|B]\neq0$. Then $x=M(aI_p\oplus bI_q)u$ and your inequality is equivalent to
$$
1+\frac{u^\ast (dM^\ast M)u}{r}
\leq 1+\frac{u^\ast(aI_p\oplus bI_q)M^\ast M(aI_p\oplus bI_q)u}{r}
\leq 1+\frac{u^\ast(cM^\ast M)u}{r}.\tag{1}
$$
If it holds for all $u$, we must have
$$
dM^\ast M
\preceq (aI_p\oplus bI_q)M^\ast M(aI_p\oplus bI_q)
\preceq cM^\ast M,\tag{2}
$$
where $X\preceq Y$ means $Y-X$ is positive semidefinite. In particular, the analogous inequality must hold for the leading principal $p\times p$ and trailing principal $q\times q$ submatrices. That is,
\begin{cases}
dA^\ast A \preceq a^2A^\ast A \preceq cA^\ast A,\\
dB^\ast B \preceq b^2B^\ast B \preceq cB^\ast B.\tag{3}
\end{cases}
Since both $A$ and $B$ are nonzero, the above implies that $d\le a^2\le c$ and $d\le b^2\le c$, i.e. $d\le d^2\le c^2\le c$. Yet, by assumption, $0<d<c$. So, the statement that $d\le d^2\le c^2\le c$ is always false and at least one case in $(3)$ is bound to fail. That is, there always exists a vector in either $\mathbb{R}^p\times 0^q$ or $0^p\times\mathbb{R}^q$ such that $(1)$ does not hold.

For an illustrative example, consider $r=1,\ a=d=\frac12,\ b=c=1$ and
$$
M=[A|B]=(1,1),\ u=\pmatrix{1\\ 0},\ y=1,\ x=\frac12.
$$
Then the first inequality sign in 
$\det(I+\frac{dyy^*}{r})=\frac32\color{red}{\le}\det(I+\frac{xx^*}{r})=\frac54\le \det(I+\frac{cyy^*}{r})=2$ is violated.

In the uninteresting cases, a similar analysis shows that your inequality holds for all $u$ iff one of the following four conditions is satisfied:

1. $A=0$ and $B=0$.
2. $A\ne0,\ B\ne0$ and $a=b=1$,
3. $A=0,\ B\ne0$ and $d\le b^2\le c$,
4. $A\ne0,\ B=0$ and $d\le a^2\le c$.

Comment: Thank you. I have made a mistake in writing the question. I it should be $dydy^*$ not $dyy^*$, same goes with $c$. I want to replace $a,b$ by their min and max. I think now My inequality is correct if I understood your proof? If you wish I can correct my question and then your can change the answer so other readers may know the correct inequality (assuming it is correct when changed). Also a small question about the notation does $(aI_p\oplus bI_q)[A\mid B]$ do same as $[aA\mid bB]$? because $A$ is not a square matrix so I don't know how $aI_pA$ can give $aA$.  Once again thank you very much.

Comment: @MLT **(1)** $aI_p\oplus bI_q$ means $\pmatrix{aI_p\\ &bI_q}$, so the matrix product is $[A|B](aI_p\oplus bI_q)$, not $(aI_p\oplus bI_q)[A|B]$. **(2)** If the $c$ and $d$ in your question are replaced by $c^2$ and $d^2$, then we would expect the inequality to hold in more cases, but it still does not hold in general. For a counterexample, consider $r=1,\ a=d=1,\ b=c=2,\ [A|B]=(2,1),\ [aA|bB]=(2,2)$. With $u=(1,-1)^T$, we get $y=1,\ x=0$ and the first inequality sign in $1+d^2y^2 = 2 \color{red}{\le} 1+x^2 = 1 \le 1+c^2y^2 = 5$ is still wrong.

Comment: But what about your claim ...implies that $d\le a^2\le c$ and $d\le b^2\le c$,... I thought it will now change to ...implies that $d^2\le a^2\le c^2$ and $d^2\le b^2\le c^2$,... which is true in my case.

Comment: @MLT If a matrix is positive semidefinite, all principal submatrices should be PSD too. It just happens that, in your first version of the problem (using $c,d$ in the inequality), the inspection of two sets of principal submatrices are enough to rule out all interesting cases. Yet in the corrected version (using $c,d$ in the inequality), $(3)$ only constitute two *necessary* conditions and they are far from being sufficient.

Comment: In the counterexample mentioned my previous comment, we have $(aI_p\oplus bI_q)M^\ast M(aI_p\oplus bI_q)-d^2M^\ast M=\pmatrix{0&2\\ 2&3}$. While the leading and trailing principal $1\times1$ submatrices (i.e. the two diagonal entries) are PSD, the matrix difference is not.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain me what are the sufficient conditions on $u$ for this the inequality to hold ?

Comment: Are you looking for conditions on $u$ such that for fixed $a,b,A,B$, the inequality holds for **this particular** $u$, or conditions on $a,b,A,B$ such that the inequality holds for **all** $u$? For the former, an obvious sufficient condition is that either the first $p$ entries of $u$ are zero or the last $q$ entries are zero. In general, the feasible region for $u$ is the intersection of two cones. We may need a numerical method to determine if the intersection is nonempty.

Comment: For the latter, let $k=b/a$. Then the first "$\preceq$" of $(2)$ (with $d$ replaced by $d^2$) in my answer is equivalent to $\pmatrix{0&kA^\ast B\\ kB^\ast A&k^2B^\ast B}\succeq0$, which is true if and only if $A^\ast B=0$. Similarly for the second "$\preceq$". So, the necessary and sufficient condition is $A^\ast B=0$.